# How to write multi level dictionary to json in tcl?

Tags: json, dictionary, tcl

I used this code

```
package req json::write

Set a [dict create]

Dict set a "k1" "lower" 0

Dict set a "k1" "upper" 20

Json::write indented true

Puts[ json::write object {*} [dict map {key value} $a {JSON::write string $val}]]
```

This prints out:

```
{
"k1" : "lower 0 upper 20"
}
```

**I was hoping for (since I think that's how right json will be)**

```
{
"K1" : [ 
"Lower" : "0",
"Upper" : "20"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, casing is important in all programming languages. Most commands also begin with a lowercase letter.

Second, the json you were expecting to get isn't quite a valid JSON. The closest I can think of is the following:

```
{ 
   "K1": { 
      "Lower":"0",
      "Upper":"20"
   }
}
```

To get the above json, you could use something like this, assuming that you only have one main key and an object of key-value pairs:

```
json::write object {*}[dict map {k v} $a {
    json::write object {*}[dict map {_k _v} $v {json::write string $_v}]
}]
```

Which gives

```
{
    "K1" : {
        "Lower" : "0",
        "Upper" : "20"
    }
}
```

---

If you want to parse any type of dict to json, I would recommend using something a bit more robust. I have been using the below for a while now without any issues (simplified from the one I use):

```
proc DictToJson { data spec {indent false}} {
    ::json::write::indented $indent
    set jsonData [dict create]
    dict for {field typeInfo} $spec {
        if {![dict exists $data $field]} {continue}
        lassign $typeInfo type meta
        set value [dict get $data $field]
        switch $type {
            object {
                set value [DictToJson $value $meta $indent]
            }
            array {
                set value [ListToJsonArray $value {*}$meta]
            }
            string {
                set value [::json::write string $value]
            }
            bare {}
            default {
                return -code error "Unknown type: $type"
            }
        }
        dict set jsonData $field $value
    }
    return [::json::write object {*}$jsonData]
}

proc ListToJsonArray {list type {meta {}}} {
    set jsonArray [list]
    switch $type {
        object {
            foreach element $list {
                lappend jsonArray [DictToJson $element $meta false]
            }
        }
        array {
            lassign $meta subtype submeta
            foreach element $list {
                lappend jsonArray \
                        [ListToJsonArray $element $subtype $submeta]
            }
        }
        string {
            foreach element $list {
                lappend jsonArray [::json::write string $element]
            }
        }
        bare {
            set jsonArray $list
        }
        default {
            return -code error "Invalid array element type: $type"
        }
    }
    return [::json::write array {*}$jsonArray]
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
# Create the dict
set a [dict create K1 {lower 0 upper 20}]
# This defines the value type for each key
set spec {K1 {object {lower string upper string}}}

DictToJson $a $spec true
```

Which gives the same results.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm.

For my info - if i wanted to print only second level key value pairs, instead of K1 in our little example, what changes in our code? Many thanks again!

Comment: @vaibhavsharma That would be `json::write object {*}[dict map {k v} [dict get $a K1] {json::write string $v}]` or if you are certain there is only one top key/value pair in the dict, then `json::write object {*}[dict map {k v} {*}[dict values $a] {json::write string $v}]`

Comment: @Jerry Can you help me with this JSON below? I am having trouble trying a spec for it while using ListToJsonArray proc. Much appreciated. { "data" : { "accountId" : "1234", "fields": { "K1": [{ "lower": 0, "upper": 20 }] } } }

Comment: @sadhat75 `set spec {data {object {accountId string fields {object {K1 {array {object {lower string upper string}}}}}}}}`